# Activate ContextMenuStrip when the Form doesn't have focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, contextmenustrip

1. I am able to display ContextMenuScript (CMS) successfully outside windows form.
2. I can Select/Click items using mouse pointer.
3. However, it doesn't likes keyboard control (arrow up/down, escape) when form is not focused.
4. If the form is focused and CMS showed, then keyboard can control it but not when not focused :(.
5. I need help with code which will help to achieve this without form being focused.

Regards

```
   Public Const CTRL_Key As Integer = &H2
   Public Const Hot_Key As Integer = &H312
   Public Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
   Public Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer

   Private Sub Hot_Key_Register() Handles MyBase.Load
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, CTRL_Key, Keys.NumPad1)
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 200, CTRL_Key, Keys.NumPad2)
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 300, CTRL_Key, Keys.NumPad3)
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef Window_Message As Message)

    If Window_Message.Msg = Hot_Key Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = Window_Message.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)
            Case "100"
                CMS_01.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
            Case "200"
                CMS_02.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
            Case "300"
                CMS_03.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(Window_Message)
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - Using NotifyIcon**

The easiest fix which you can use is using an invisible [`NotifyIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/notifyicon-component-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) component as it handles this case in its internal [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NotifyIcon.cs,fc0e2a272ada0b8f).

Drop an instance of `NotifyIcon` on your form and then to use it for showing context menu, assign the context menu strip to its [`ContextMenuStrip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/contextmenustrip-control?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property and then call its `ShowContextMenu` private method using reflection.

*Example*

```
Private Sub ShowContextMenu(menu As ContextMenuStrip)
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = menu
    Dim m = NotifyIcon1.GetType().GetMethod("ShowContextMenu",
        Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    m.Invoke(NotifyIcon1, Nothing)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef Window_Message As Message)
    If Window_Message.Msg = Hot_Key Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = Window_Message.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)
            Case "100"
                ShowContextMenu(CMS_01)
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(Window_Message)
End Sub
```

**Option 2 - Using Native Window**

And here is the fix without using [`NotifyIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/notifyicon-component-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), using [`NativeWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). The following piece of code cares about the active window and if the current form is active, it doesn't use the native window, otherwise it creates and uses native window.

*Example*

```
Private window As NativeWindow
Private Sub ShowContextMenu(menu As ContextMenuStrip, p As Point)
    If (Form.ActiveForm IsNot Me) Then
        If (window Is Nothing) Then
            window = New NativeWindow()
            window.CreateHandle(New CreateParams())
        End If
        SetForegroundWindow(window.Handle)
    End If
    menu.Show(p)
End Sub
```

And show the menu:

```
ShowContextMenu(CMS_01, Cursor.Position)
```

Just keep in mind to release the window handle when closing/disposing the form:

```
If (window IsNot Nothing) Then
    window.DestroyHandle()
    window = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Hi Reza, Thank you very much for this code. Both the methods you've outlined do helped me to achieve what i want; however, there is slight issue. (A). The CMS will not show at the first time after hotkey pressed but a small cross button box will appear on the screen. (B) The same cross button box will remain on the screen. It will be best if you can provide me the solution for hiding this box or may be it can appear in the system tray. Thank you again :)

Comment: Hi JD, I checked the solution again and I couldn't reproduce any of the issues. I'm working on 10 Version 1709.

Comment: Make sure you have registered the hotkeys correctly (after the form has been shown) also make sure you always unregister them correctly (on closing or dispose), and also if you used the `NativeWindow` solution, make sure you dispose the window correctly (on closing or dispose).

Comment: Hi Reze, yes you're right. The code is perfect. I've marked it and answered. Thanks a ton. The small box was of child form that I added during testing. Thanks a ton :)